# Libgdx | Make part of player sprite black when exists game area

Tags: android, libgdx, desktop

I have a game where I clear the background black. I then have a white circle in the center of the screen for the game area, that is almost as tall as the viewport height. The player is inside this white circle, and I want to make it so that if he leaves, whatever part of him that isn't in the play area turns black (not visible essentially because the background is cleared black).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a PointLight using rayHandler without ambient light, like this:

```
rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);
rayHandler.setShadows(true);

PointLight pt = new PointLight(rayHandler, 120, Color.WHITE, circle_radius, circle_center_x, circle_center_Y);
pt.setSoftnessLength(4f);
```